# Can I convert a ".py" or ".ipynb" model/file created on Google Colab's Tensorflow to a coreML model/ file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, coreml

I created a CNN model on Google Colab's Tensorflow and downloaded the file as a ".py" file. How can I convert this file into a ".coreml" file?

Any advice is much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: .py files are Python source code files. This is not a machine learning model. You'll also need to download the actual trained CNN model file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation on how to convert into Core ML's `.mlmodel`s: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/converting_trained_models_to_core_ml

For TensorFlow models, you need to convert it to `frozen.pb` model as an input for the convert function. Here are some examples: https://github.com/tf-coreml/tf-coreml/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded a `.py` file you haven't downloaded the model, but the whole Python script.

When you have your model compiled, you can use the python package `coremltools` to convert the TensorFlow/Keras model into a `.mlmodel` file.

```py
import coremltools

core_mlmodel = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(your_keras_model, respect_trainable=True)
core_mlmodel.save("YourModel.mlmodel")
```

Then you will find your model on the left in `Files`.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. Much appreciated. I'm learning about multi output  model and tried to use this function to convert the .h5 model to coreml. I use this following script for this conversion. However, when I run this coreml model in Xcode, there's always an error saying that " The size of the output layer 'output2' in the neural network does not match the number of classes in the classifier."I'm sure I've listed correct number of classes. Any advice on how to resolve this issue is much appreciated? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@ Sebastian J. Vogt. This is my conversion code. Is it correct? Thank you!

```
import coremltools

category_output_labels = ['dress', 'shirt', 'trousers']
color_output_labels = ['black', 'blue', 'green', 'pink', 'red', 
'white']

coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert('./fashion_multi_output_v02.h5',
```

input_names='image', image_input_names='image', class_labels=['category_output_labels', 'color_output_labels'])